# Merging state and static data for display in Angular using ngrx/store

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm new to ngrx store and am having trouble wrapping my head around how to efficiently couple the state of my application with the static objects that drive my components.

**items.ts**

```
export class Item {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    count: number;
    need: number;
}

export class ItemState {
    id: number;
    count: number;
}

export class ItemStateAction implements Action {
    type: string;
    id: number;
    count: number;
}

export function itemReducer(
    state: ItemState,
    action: ItemStateAction
) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_VALUE:
            if (state.id === action.id) {
                return (state. = action.count);
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I'm making an app that has a pre-defined list of items that allows the user to adjust the count of each item.

I have an `ItemListComponent` that is in charge of fetching the items from the `ItemService`, which just returns an `Observable<Item[]>`, imported from a static file.

**item.service.ts**

```
...
import { Item } from "./item";
import { ITEMS } from "./static-items";

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
    constructor() {}

    getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
        return of(ITEMS);
    }
}
```

**item-list.component.ts**

```
...
import { ItemService } from "../item.service";
import { Item } from "../item";

export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit {
    items: Item[];

    constructor(private itemService: ItemService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getItems();
    }

    getItems(): void {
        this.itemService
            .getItems()
            .subscribe(items => (this.items = items));
    }
}
```

Should I query the store in the item-list (parent) component and merge the `Observable<Item[]>` with an `Observable<ItemState[]>` from the store?  Or should I use the static item and query the store for the specific item state in the item sub-component? I know the sub-component is supposed to be "dumb", so the latter seems to go against that.

I am also using the `Item`s in part of another structure where a subset is contained in an array.

Model for another view:

```
export class Requirement {
    id: number;
    items: Item[];
}

//example
//Requirement[] = [ {'id': 1, items: [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Apple', need: 3, count: 0}] },
//  {'id': 2, items: [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Apple', need: 2, count: 0}] }]
```

For this structure I'd have to get the item state from the store and then assign counts to each of the items in each of the requirements, or query the store each time an item sub-component is rendered for an accurate count.  Is there a "best practice" for this kind of thing? Sorry if this is too unclear or abstract.

Comment: you have any kind of store defined?, you should define the reducer that change the state of your store and the actions that call the specific reducer

Comment: Updated with reducer and item state.  I'm more asking an architecture question, like where should I be changing/querying the state of my store

Answer (score 0):

In your service you need to import the store from `ngrx`

```
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store"
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

constructor(private store: Store<any>) { }

getItems() {
   return this.store.select("items")
}
}
```

the `getItems` method will select from your store the list of items. "items" should be defined as a part of your store en the module declaration

to change the state of your store is better if you declare a class that contain a type action that match with the actions in your reducer  (SET_VALUE)

```
export class SetValue implements Action {
    readonly type = SET_VALUE
    constructor(public value: any) { }
}
```

and then to call this action you can just declare the class action and passed to the store

```
setValue(value:any) {
    this.store.dispatch(new SetValue(value))
  }
```

your reducer will look like

```
export function itemReducer(
    state: ItemState = staticValues,
    action: ItemStateAction
) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_VALUE:
            if (state.id === action.id) {
                return (state. = action.count);
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

this is how I usually do, let me know if that clarify your question

Comment: So how would I combine that with the static data (name, etc imported from static-items.ts).  Would you keep that in the store too?

Comment: you need to declare the store (the reducer) with a default value, put this static data there